# login using "ec2-user" instead of root using user data in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I have an Amazon EC2 instance based off of a RHEL 6.4 64bit AMI. After writing some shell scripts; I created my own AMI Image off of it.

I'm writing user data section which will remove the contents under /home/ec2-user(sudo rm -rf /home/ec2-user/*) and then execute that script. But i'm unable to remove any files.

what I want:

- I want to remove files.
- One more weird use case I've, by default user data section enters as "root" user but is there possibility to enter as "ec2-user" user and get my work done..?

Answer (score 24):

User data always runs as root so don't use sudo. Below runs the cmd as ec2-user. If you want to start an executable do so in the background (ie. add `&` at the end)

`su ec2-user -c 'do whatever you want; ./run.sh &'`

Comment: Surely its not necessary to run it in the background. My script shuts down the instance after its done so I don't make it run in the background. Does that affect how the user running works?

Comment: Worth mentioning, values of $PATH and $HOME variables are preserved from the root user environment.

Comment: @antonbormotov you can use `su - ec2-user -c 'echo "$HOME $USER"'` it will output as `/home/ec2-user ec2-user`. Note the single quotes 1st then double quotes

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it in the normal ec2-user account Do this command to be the ***deploy*** user ...

```
sudo su - deploy
```

which will then allow you to go to your app at the current location ...

```
cd /srv/www/sample_app/current
```