# AWS EC2 user data: run python script at startup as non-root user

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, su, ec2-userdata

When my EC2 VM (Ubuntu) starts, I'd like it to execute a python script `myscript.py` as `ec2-user` instead of the default `root` user. This includes using the `ec2-user`'s python executable, installed packages and binaries (e.g. chromedriver)

How can I do this?

What I did/ tried so far:

- logged in as `ec2-user`, I verified that `python myscript.py`, `python --version` and `which python` work as intended
- logged in as `root`, running `python` results in `Command 'python' not found`
- logged in as `root`, running `su ec2-user -c python` results in `Command 'python' not found`. Same result with `sudo -u ec2-user bash -c 'python --version'`
- logged in as `root`, running `/path/to/ec2-user/python_executable /path/to/myscript.py` does start the script, but crashes due not not finding binaries (e.g. chromedriver)
- adding `su ec2-user -c 'echo "Switched to User ${USER} with $(python --version) in $(which python)" >> /path/to/logfile.log'` adds the line `Switched to User ec2-user with  in`  to the logfile, hence does not assume the `ec2-user` user when calling `python`

So, how can I make my user `ec2-user` execute `myscript.py` within the execution of the user data at instance startup?

references:

- [login using "ec2-user" instead of root using user data in aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157432/login-using-ec2-user-instead-of-root-using-user-data-in-aws)
- [Running command in UserData as a not-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57443700/running-command-in-userdata-as-a-not-root-user)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: The user-data script runs as root but you can sudo to any given user e.g. `sudo -u ubuntu whoami`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by using a `cronjob` with `@reboot`, running the desired commands at every startup